# Advanced Forum: Hide Form Label

Tags: entities, nodes

How can I hide the label of form in advanced forum?

[image]

My content type:forum topic->comment display->comment:label is already set to be hidden

Edit : I realised that it's a form

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into the Drupal 7 admin dashboard.
2. Using the top menu bar, locate and click on the Structure option.
3. From this next page, click on the Content Types link.
4. On the Content Types page, find the type of content you want to work with. I have been working with Basic Pages so I will stick with that. After locating your desired content type, click on the correct Manage Display link.
5. From this page you will need to find the filed row  you want to hide and then the Label dropdown. Set the Label field to  to remove the label from the image field.
6. Once finished, click on the Save button at the bottom.
7. Clear cache

Or you can use Automatic [Nodetitles module](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)

"auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.

Comment: Thanks. However I just realised that I was facing problems because it was a form.